# How to change destination jar directory

Tags: sbt

How to change destination directory of jars getting downloaded by sbt in libraryDependencies.
I want to change it to some thing like $HOME/custom_jars rather than its default one ($HOME/.ivy2/....)

Thanks,
Abhinandan

Comment: Do you want one directory per project, or a single shared directory for all projects?

Comment: I need one directory per project, which I should be able to configure in .sbt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `retrieveManaged` to `true` causes sbt to create a `lib_managed` directory in your project directory and to put your dependency jars there.

The directory name is used is controlled by `managedDirectory` and defaults to `baseDirectory.value / "lib_managed"`, but you can set it to something else if you like.